# How to fill color to empty space with overflow hidden?

Tags: css

I have simple CSS where I can display image with prescribed width and height. If I put image height is more than width I can fill the box easily. But when I upload image having more width and less height. The bottom part of image remains vacant or empty space.

Help me to fill that empty space marked with black cirle in image below. Whatever method will do.

[image]

CSS

```
.container4 {
     width: 9.5em;
     overflow: scroll;
     height: 10em;
 }
.container4 img {
     width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to stretch the image?

Comment: add background-color:transparent; to the container

Comment: Why not add `height:*your container height*` in your image? But the picture will be stretched.

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover;` may be a useful property for you.
http://jsfiddle.net/uTHqs/

Comment: This could be a comment.

Comment: It could be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you set height to 100% and don't set width it will fill the whole frame, but the picture will get cut off, otherwise you can tile the image.

Comment: What if it's a tall image?

Comment: Then it will fill the height, but you may have some extra on the width. If you're just looking to fill the background with something. You can have both a background-color and a background-image and it will fill the rest of the frame with the color.

Comment: So the answer that would ensure no unfilled space would be using a css background and the background-size:cover. If you want to ensure that the whole picture is displayed you can use contain instead. http://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: sure, but cover will trim some of the image. You're right it does always ensure that the whole element is covered, though